# ColdFusion: how to clear specific fields in a database row

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, survey

I'm making a survey for graduated college seniors to fill out based on their post-grad plans. I'm not sure how to reset or clear particular fields for the update page.

pg1.cfm, the user logs in with their student ID. Several fields are auto-populated from data related to their ID, such as major and GPA.

pg2.cfm, the user answers a series of questions about their post-grad plans. Different questions are shown based on their response to the first question. If the questions are already answered, a blurb appears, directing the user to update their plans at update.cfm.

pg3.cfm, updates the database with answers from pg2.cfm and asks a few more questions about internship opportunities.

update.cfm, the same questions from pg2.cfm are shown. As it stands, update.cfm appends the new response to the database field instead of replacing the existing answer. Because of the nature of the survey - different fields are filled based on which fieldset of questions the user answers - I figure the most efficient way would be to just clear out all the possible question-based fields when the form is submitted and then repopulate them with the new answers. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: *just clear out all the possible question-based fields* Possibly, but it would help to see your current query and a sample of the actual versus desired results.

Comment: Your description is *way* too vague. Please include your code in the question Reduce to under 10 lines per CFM file, including any SQL (this should be doable if you concentrate on the important bits).

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to help without code. When you're asking a question about code, it's usually quite helpful to provide the relevant code.

Before I continue, I could see value in keeping the old answers as well, you can chart how a user has displayed data.

If your table is in the simple format

```
Answers
AnswerID | StudentID | Answer1 | Answer2 | ... | Answer10
```

Upon submitting update.cfm, this code would work

```
<cfquery...>
  delete from Answers
   where StudentID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.studentID#">
</cfquery>

<cfquery...>
  insert into Answers(StudentID,Answer1,Answer2,...,Answer10)
  values (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.studentID#">,
          <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.Answer1#">,
          <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.Answer2#">,
          <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.Answer10#">)
</cfquery>
```

(If you're not using `cfqueryparam`, you need to. It prevents sql injection.)

Personally, I probably wouldn't delete the old data, I'd datestamp it and track it, but it's not my application.

Now, the better way to do this is with three/five tables. It is more complex, but it's the best way to handle custom answers and

```
Students (or users table, whatever you call it)
StudentID, Name, Zipcode ...

Questions
QuestionID | QuestionSetID | QuestionText
----[sample data]------------------------
1          | 1             | What is your age
2          | 1             | How quickly do you expect to find a job in your field

Answers
AnswerID | StudentID | QuestionID | AnswerText

QuestionSetNames
QuestionSetID | QuestionSetName=
1             | "Psych Degree question set"
2             | "Computer Science question set"
```

To begin with, you would/could create a QuestionSets, because, as you said, you provide different questions based on input provided.

Questions don't have to be unique to question sets. You could include any question in any question set.

So, with Questions in in the questions table you would decide which question set you wanted to ask a person. and query for it like this

```
<cfquery...name="GetQuestions">
  select * from Questions
   where QuestionSetID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#setID#">
</cfquery>

<form...><cfoutput><input type="hidden" name="Questions" value="#valuelist(GetQuestions.QUestion)#"></cfoutput>
<cfoutput query="GetQuestions">
  #QuestionText#:<br />
  <input type="text" name="AnswerForQ_#questionID#"...>
</cfoutput></form>
```

Process that with

```
<cfloop list="#form.Questions#" index="i">
  <cfquery...>
    delete from Answers
     where StudentID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.studentID#">
  </cfquery>

  <cfquery...>
    INSERT INTO Answers(StudentID,QuestionID,AnswerText)
    values(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.studentID#">,
           <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#i#">,
           <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form["AnswerForQ_#i#"]#">)
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

And then you can query that with

```
<cfquery name="GetAnswers">
  select QuestionText,AnswerText from Answers,Questions
   where StudentID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.studentID#">
     and Answers.AnswerID = Questions.QuestionID
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#QuestionText#: #AnswerText#<br /></cfoutput>
```

There's still a lot of code you'd need to write, administrative capability for adding questions / question sets mainly.

You could either add a timestamp to the Answers table (that all answers for the same submission would share), or you could make an intermediary AnswerSheets table to hold the timestamp and add a corresponding AnswerSheetID to Answers.

It may seem like a good bit more work, but it really pays off when you're trying to add to questions sets or, moreso, trying to analyze the data. Plus, once it's in place, someone else can administer it. So it's more work right now, less work later.